# html canvas linewidth not working properly

Tags: jquery, canvas, line

I was drawing a few lines in canvas using javascript and I was changing the value of linewidth for 3 different lines (the two axes, bottom 10 lines and top 10 lines). When I change the `lineWidth` property for the first 2 lines (lineWidth = 2.5 and lineWidth = 1.0), it works fine. However, when I add the last lineWidth property = 2.0, it does not work and it changes. I have placed the code in this fiddle. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwp2ps09/1/

```
<canvas id="graph" width="550" height="400"></canvas>

$(document).ready(function(){
var p= 50;
graph = $('#graph');
var g = graph[0].getContext('2d');

drawlines();

function drawlines(){
    g.beginPath();
    //brings cursor to the origin of this line graph
    g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p);
    //creates x-axis
    g.lineTo(graph.width() - p, graph.height() - p);
    g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p);
    //creates y-axis
    g.lineTo(p, p);
    g.lineWidth = 2.5;
    g.font = '12px Arial';
    g.stroke();

    g.lineWidth = 1.0;

    for (i=10; i<101; i+=10){
        g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p - i);
        //creates x-axis
        g.lineTo(graph.width() - p, graph.height() - p - i);
    }
    g.stroke();

    g.lineWidth = 2.0;

    for (i=110; i<201; i+=10){
        g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p - i);
        //creates x-axis
        g.lineTo(graph.width() - p, graph.height() - p - i);
    }
    g.stroke();
}
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember to use `beginPath()` before you add new lines. The path will be rendered with the latest set line-width. `beginPath()` will clear the previous path and the lines that are added.

If you don't clear the path the new `stroke()` call will stroke the newly added lines on top of the old lines. And as the line-width is thicker the new lines will simply overdraw the old ones.

**Updated code (from the fiddle):**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var p = 50;
  graph = $('#graph');
  var g = graph[0].getContext('2d');

  drawlines();

  function drawlines() {
    g.beginPath();
    //brings cursor to the origin of this line graph
    g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p);
    //creates x-axis
    g.lineTo(graph.width() - p, graph.height() - p);
    g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p);
    //creates y-axis
    g.lineTo(p, p);
    g.lineWidth = 2.5;
    g.font = '12px Arial';
    g.stroke();

    g.beginPath();  // <--- Define new path here

    g.lineWidth = 1.0;

    for (i = 10; i < 101; i += 10) {
      g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p - i);
      //creates x-axis
      g.lineTo(graph.width() - p, graph.height() - p - i);
    }
    g.stroke();

    g.beginPath();  // <--- and here, etc.

    g.lineWidth = 2.0;

    for (i = 110; i < 201; i += 10) {
      g.moveTo(p, graph.height() - p - i);
      //creates x-axis
      g.lineTo(graph.width() - p, graph.height() - p - i);
    }
    g.stroke();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
```